# How to create a VoIP push production certificate?

Tags: php, ios, ssl, voip

I would like to create a VoIP certificate for production, but it seems to not be working.

Here's what I did:

- Created a new production certificate for VoIP on developer.apple.com with the corresponding App ID
- Downloaded the certificate and opened it with my keychain
- Exported the certificate and the key both to create a .p12 file
- Used this line with OpenSSL to create a .pem file

> openssl pkcs12 -in Certificate.p12 -out VoIP.pem -clcerts -nodes

- Created a php script to send a payload with the .pem file to *`ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`*

I got the success callback from the server, triple checked the device ID and nothing seems to be happening.

However, if I set the url to *`ssl://gateway.sandbox.apple.com:2195`*, everything works accordingly.

But that is not the result I want, I would like it to work with the correct production server.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue :( . If you resolved this issue can you please tell me.